# When I attempting to add my code to repository on GitHub I'm getting error like this "Failed to push to the remote repositor..."

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, github

I want publish  my code to github but i have problem because I'm getting this error in visual studio.

> "Failed to push to the remote repository. See the Output window for more details."

In output window:

> Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
>   HttpRequestException encountered. cannot spawn askpass: No such file or directory
>   could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled

I'm trying this [Git failed with a > fatal error. could not read Username for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47997966/git-failed-with-a-fatal-error-could-not-read-username-for) but it's doesn't work.

Someone will tell me what else I can do ? I will add that two days ago everything was ok.

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/issues/949

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For security purposes, github remove one security protocol to connect to github and break a lot of client.

See this document to fix it:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/201457/unable-to-connect-to-github-due-to-tls-12-only-cha.html