# Visual studio 2017 cant push to git

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

i am having issues to push to git from visual studio 2017, i had no issues in the past with it, and the exact same project with the same version of visual studio, but suddenly it stopped working, i have no idea why, basically i am getting this error.

> Unable to complete read operation after process has exited.
>   Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
>   HttpRequestException encountered.
>      An error occurred while sending the request.
>   cannot spawn /C/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/Team Explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-askpass.exe: No such file or directory
>   could not read Password for 'https://xxx@bitbucket.org': terminal prompts disabled
>   Pushing to https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx.git

if i use the CMD, i have no issues, everything works fine there.

any thoughts how to fix it in visual studio 2017 community edition?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue updating Git Credential Manager for Windows to the latest  -> 
https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases

Comment: Your response got me on the right track. This was my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52999645/5248400