# Unable to clone branches repo from https://microsoftit.visualstudio.com in Visual Studio Team Explorer

Tags: .net, visual-studio, azure-devops

I'm getting below error while trying to clone a branch from `https://microsoftit.visualstudio.com/` in Visual Studio 2019 Team Exploprer.

[image]

How to resolve that?

Comment: Is this your account or account of your organization?

Comment: I'm working for an organization. I have access to the repo and it is provided by organization. Earlier in another system I used to clone code. Today I'm trying clone in another machine and faced mentioned issue.

Comment: Did you try solution described here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47997966/git-failed-with-a-fatal-error-could-not-read-username-for

Comment: I have rebooted the system. Then it started working.Thanks you all for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

Op verified after rebooted the system, it started working again. Everything went back to the track.

---

According to your description "Earlier in another system I used to clone code." and error message in the screenshot.

This should be a **client related issue**. Mainly caused by the credentials have been cached by Credential Manager. You should remove the credentials for `https://microsoftit.visualstudio.com/`  which have been stored in Credential Manager.

Besides, just as Shamrai Aleksander mentioned in the comment, you could also give a try with other option in similar issue here: [Git failed with a > fatal error. could not read Username for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47997966/git-failed-with-a-fatal-error-could-not-read-username-for)

> Managed to fix this issue by deleting a this file:
>   "C:\Users(profile)\AppData\Local\GitCredentialManager\tenant.cache".
>   On the next retry, a GIT entry showed up in my Windows Credentials
>   generic list.