# Cannot clone from Azure DevOps or from VS-2017

Tags: git, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017

Having problem authenticating in Git and downloaded the latest version Git for Windows from Azure DevOps.  Attached is the screenshot of the error (appears either from cloning from Azure DevOps or from VS-2017 Team Explorer.   I believe I don't know where to setup the username login authentication?  [Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecMIL.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git failed with a > fatal error. could not read Username for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47997966/git-failed-with-a-fatal-error-could-not-read-username-for)

Comment: Thanks - that fixed it -- I was also able to find info about a VS   TF30063 error

Comment: Glad that it worked for you.